# Object detection in image

Tags: image-processing

I have the following `image`, with a "large" object and 3 visible bright pixels:

[image]

What I do not understand:

Why do I count in the this `image` more pixels with brightness $\ge0$ (= 191688) than pixels are available (326$\cdot$294 = 95844). Also is not clear to me why so many pixels have brightness = 1.

```
image = ColorConvert[image, "Grayscale"]

dim = ImageDimensions[image]
{326, 294}

dim[[1]]*dim[[2]]
95844

Count[Flatten[ImageData[image]], a_ /; a >= 0]
191688

Count[Flatten[ImageData[image]], a_ /; a == 1]
95843
```

Accordingly, the histogram of the `image` is surprising:

```
Histogram[Flatten@ImageData@image, {0, 1.01, 0.01}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

As next I wanted to measure the mean brightness center of the large object.
Here I do not understand why the `resultingImage` includes the bright pixels visible in the original `image` and also has pixels with brightness $\ge0$, although the binarized image `binImage` containes only pixels with brightness of = 0 and = 1.

What am I doing wrong?

```
binImage = Binarize[image, 0.4]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[Flatten@ImageData@binImage, {0, 1.01, 0.01}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

```
resultingImage = ImageMultiply[image, binImage]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[Flatten@ImageData@resultingImage, {0, 1.01, 0.01}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

The following code measured the center of the large object and the three bright pixels:

```
meanValue = ComponentMeasurements[resultingImage, "Centroid"]
{1 -> {170.5, 231.5}, 2 -> {125.372, 172.731}, 3 -> {94.5, 70.5}, 4 -> {175.5, 70.5}}
```

Comment: Your image seems to have 2 channels, which is why `Length@Flatten[ImageData[image]]` is twice the value of `dim[[1]]*dim[[2]]`

Comment: How could I solve that and why do have half of the pixles in `image` brightness=1?

Comment: the second channel seems to be just flat white, so I say throw it out, see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason those 3 bright pixels are located in the second channel of your image, while the bright spot is in the first channel,

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Gu8.png"];
{Image[ImageData[image][[All, All, 1]]], 
 Image[ImageData[image][[All, All, 2]]]}
```

[image]

So you could just throw out that second channel, which seems to have a flat brightness,

```
image = Image[ImageData[image][[All, All, 1]]]
ImageMultiply[image, Binarize[blackimage, 0.4]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ... now I have looked into the original 4K image. It has only one channel. But when I cropped the image with xnview and saved it this strange 2 channel image was produced. You solved my problem.

Comment: @mrz glad I could help

Comment: You mean `ColorSeparate`?